# Setting up Ruby Gems on Mac OS

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to setup ruby on my Mac OSX El Capitan to install gems in a "non standard" location, that is I would like to have everything gem-related installed by myself in the directory `/opt/Ruby/gems`.

Ruby and gem are already installed:

```
> which gem
/usr/bin/gem
> which ruby 
/usr/bin/ruby
```

When I try to install [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com), everything seems to work fine and Jekyll and its dependencies are installed in `/opt/Ruby/gems` (this directory is already in the $PATH):

```
> ls -l /opt/Ruby/gems/bin/
total 64
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  508 18 Feb 00:11 jekyll*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  516 18 Feb 00:11 kramdown*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  508 18 Feb 00:11 listen*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  506 18 Feb 00:11 rougify*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  520 18 Feb 00:11 safe_yaml*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  500 18 Feb 00:11 sass*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  508 18 Feb 00:11 sass-convert*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pmca  wheel  500 18 Feb 00:11 scss*
```

However, when I try to run Jekyll, I get the following error:

```
> jekyll -h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /opt/Ruby/gems/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

The same happens if I try to run the other gems that were installed with Jekyll so it should be something with the configuration I have to gem but I can't get to know where is the trouble. When I run `gem environment --debug` things look fine (for me...):

```
> gem environment --debug
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /opt/Ruby/gems
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/"]
     - "install" => "--install-dir /opt/Ruby/gems"
     - "gempath" => ["/opt/Ruby/gems", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0", "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

And the `.gemrc` file is like the following:

```
---
:backtrace: true
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
install: --install-dir /opt/Ruby/gems
gempath:
- /opt/Ruby/gems
- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

What is gem missing and how can I fix this?

**Edit 1**: following comments the content of `/opt/Ruby/gems/bin/jekyll` looks to be a wrapper script not a binary:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'jekyll' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'jekyll', version
load Gem.bin_path('jekyll', 'jekyll', version)
```

ruby and gem are executables (not links):

```
> ls -l /usr/bin/ | egrep 'ruby|gem'
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root   wheel       596 23 Aug  2015 gem*
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     42864  5 May  2016 ruby*
```

Comment: It's possible that jekyll itself has hard-coded something, and isn't picking up your custom configuration

Comment: I see, but the same error happens when running the other dependencies (e.g. kramdown or sass) which I would say are independent of the Jekyll code.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/ruby` and `ls -l /usr/bin/gem`? Are they symlinks to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby`, for instance?

Comment: Also, what's the content of the file `/opt/Ruby/gems/bin/jekyll`? Is it a compiled binary, or a Ruby script wrapper around a binary elsewhere?

Comment: Good observations, I will update my question with your suggestions. It seems that /opt/Ruby/gems/bin/jekyll is wrapper around another script.

Comment: Ah, yup. You can see in the top of the wrapper script that the Ruby executable being used in the `jekyll` executable is `#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby`, not `/usr/bin/ruby`. You should probably start searching for how to make sure your gem wrappers (sometimes called "binstubs"?) use the correct Ruby executable for your custom configuration.